# Setting a custom long list of starting URLS in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

The crawling starts from the list included in `start_urls = []`

I need a long list of these starting urls and 2 methods of solving this problem:

**Method 1:** Using `pandas` to define the `starting_urls` array

```
#Array of Keywords 
keywords = pandas.Keyword
urls = {}
count = 0
while(count < 100):
     urls[count]='google.com?q=' + keywords[count]
     count = count + 1
#Now I have the starting urls in urls array.
```

However, it doesn't seem to define `starting_urls = urls` because when I run:

```
scrapy crawl SPIDER
```

I get the error:

> Error: Request url must be str or unicode, got int:

**Method 2:**

Each starting URL *contains paginated content* and in the `def parse` method I have the following code to crawl all linked pages.

```
next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I want to add additional pages to crawl from the `urls` array defined above.

```
count=0
while(count < 100):
     yield response.follow(urls[count], callback=self.parse)
     count=count + 1
```

But it seems that none of these 2 methods work. Maybe I can't add this code the **spider.py** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make **first note**,  though obviously I can't say I've ran your entire script like that it's incomplete but first thing I noticed is that your face URL does need to have or be the proper format...  "http://ect.ect" for scrapy tp make a proper request

Also,  not to question your skills but if you weren't aware that by using strip,  split and join functions you can turn from list,  strings,  dictionaries add integers back and forth from each other to achieve the needed desired effect...

WHATS HAPPENING TO YOU:

## While be using range instead of count... but mimic your issue

```
lis = range(11)
site = "site.com/page="
for i in lis:
    print(site + i)
----------
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicity

#TURNING MY INT INTO STR:
lis = range(11)
site = "site.com/page="
for i in lis:
    print(site + str(i))
--------------------
site.com/page=0
site.com/page=1
site.com/page=2
site.com/page=3
site.com/page=4
site.com/page=5
site.com/page=6
site.com/page=7
site.com/page=8
site.com/page=9
site.com/page=10
```

As to the error,  when you you have the count to "+ 1",  and then configure the entire URL then to add that 1 ...  You are then trying to makes a string variable with an integer...  I'd imagine simply turning the integer into a string before then constructing your url, then back to and interger before you add one to the count so  it could be changed appropriately to then...

My go-to way to keep my coat as clean as possible is much cleaner.  By adding an extra file at the root or current working folder of which you start to crawl,  with all the urls you wish to scrape,  you can use then  pythons read and write functions and open the file with you or else decide your spider script.. like this

```
class xSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "w.e"
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
```

What really bothers me is that your error,  is saying that you're compiling drink with an integer which  I will ask you again if you need further for a complete snippet of your spider  and in the spirit of coders kinship,  also your settings.py because I'll tell you right now that who end up finding out,  despite of any adjustments to the settings.Py  file you won't be able to scrape  Google search pages... Rather,  not  entire number of result page...  Which I will then recommend to  Scrappy conjunction with beautiful suit

Comment: Thanks, the above works fine, I'm still building the spider, and using scrapy-proxies and fake-useragent to scrape the results. Will this work fine for Google?

Comment: @GRS ... For sure should get around any 403 and 506 http error response issues that Ive had doing exactly what your trying. Making sure to setup scrapy-proxies...(theres a module called scrapoxie no?) as middleware,, dont kill yourself with a bunch of prxies, as long as you can get a fresh list and exclude the medium to low s "speed" ones...

Comment: @GRS ...ALSO!

limit your congruent request super slow in settings
Enable auto-throtle and lower the AT_target concurrency request
Im sure youll run across this in your reseach and troubleshooting 
I have a deobfuscating bs4/urlib prog that lets you gather ALL hidemyass.com free proxy list, message me and ill be glad to share

Comment: please, if you could share it, would be nice

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem I see is that you are making a DICT when it expects a list. :).  Change it to a list.

There are also all kinds of interactions depending on which underlying spider you inherited from (if you did at all).  Try switching to list then hit the question up again with more data if you still are having problems

Comment: Thanks, I see. I tried first doing something like urls=[] and then urls[]='google.com?q=' + keyword[count] but it returned invalid syntax error

Comment: The syntax is `urls=['item1','item2','item3']`.  Python is type lazy.  Most of the type denotation is on the right side of the = :)

Comment: So the only way I can do this is by: urls = [None] * 100 and then populate it using correct indexing?

Comment: or urls = [None] * len(keywords)? The poblem is, that is seems keywords (from pandas) is an object. I'm not sure if it's a list.

Comment: I would use list comprehension to form your array from the object given by pandas(I've never used pandas so you will have to adapt to match pandas object structure).  Something like: `urls=['google.com?q='+keyword for keyword in pandas.keyword]`